# Returning an unique line from multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

I'm trying to return a single description if the primary key are equal, for example, I have this return:

```
CD_TABLE | DS_TABLE | DS_ANOTHER_TABLE
------   | ------   | ------
1        | TEST-01  | TEST-X 
2        | TEST-02  | TEST-Y
2        | TEST-02  | TEST-W
3        | TEST-03  | TEST-Z
```

As second and third rows are the same information at the first column, is there  a way to return this way?

```
CD_TABLE | DS_TABLE | DS_ANOTHER_TABLE
------   | ------   | ------
1        | TEST-01  | TEST-X 
2        | TEST-02  | TEST-Y, TEST-W
3        | TEST-03  | TEST-Z
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`listagg`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function seems to fit the bill:

```
SELECT   cd_table, ds_table,
         LISTAGG(ds_another_table, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ds_another_table)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY cd_table, ds_table
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `LISTAGG` has some limitations. If the result of concatenation results in more than 4000 characters, it will return an error.

Comment: @HepC . . . That is less a limitation of `listagg()` than a limitation of the string data types in Oracle in general.  You have the same problem is you try to concatenate strings using `||`.

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik, but it worked with "WITHIN GROUP". Why my question received negative vote?

Comment: @dsd The "with" was indeed a typo, it should have been "within", fixed, thanks! As for the downvote - it wasn't me that downvoted it.

Comment: @Mureinik no problem, thanks again.